# How to connect gremlin with bitsy database?

Tags: groovy, gremlin, bitsy

I've been trying to connect to a Bitsy graphDB which already contains some data from gremlin 2.5.0(groovy).

I'm doing this from the gremlin shell and haven't yet tried referencing the classes from eclipse.

```
gremlin> BitsyGraph g = new BitsyGraph(java.nio.file.Paths.get('/home/ubuntu/BitsyDB');
```

However I'm getting the following error:

```
groovysh_evaluate: 54: unable to resolve class BitsyGraph
```

I've already done an import of the package `com.lambdazen.bitsy.*` and the import worked.

How do I get this to work? Or should I write a groovy script with all these commands or can we write a gremlin script? I am new to graph DB :)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues here.  First, note that Bitsy is officially compatible with TinkerPop 2.4.0 not 2.5.0, so while it might work in the 2.5.0 Gremlin Console, I would recommend going backward to 2.4.0.

Next, you have to be a little careful with `.*` imports as they aren't validated:

```
gremlin> import anything.that.i.want.*
==>import com.tinkerpop.gremlin.*
...
==>import anything.that.i.want.*
```

Finally, the reason your class can't be found is because Bitsy is not a TinkerPop maintained Blueprints implementation and therefore does not ship with the Gremlin distribution.  You can do one of two things:

1. Copy the Bitsy jar files to the Gremlin classpath - be sure to get all dependencies or it may not work properly.
2. Use Grape to pull Bitsy in for your Gremlin Console session

For the latter, you can issue the following commands:

```
gremlin> Grape.grab([group:'com.lambdazen.bitsy',module:'bitsy',version:'1.5.1'])
==>null
gremlin> import com.lambdazen.bitsy.BitsyGraph                                   
==>import com.tinkerpop.gremlin.*
==>import com.tinkerpop.gremlin.java.*
...
==>import com.lambdazen.bitsy.BitsyGraph
gremlin> import java.nio.file.*                                                  
==>import com.tinkerpop.gremlin.*
==>import com.tinkerpop.gremlin.java.*
...
==>import java.nio.file.*
gremlin> dbPath = Paths.get("/tmp/bitsy")                                        
==>tmp
==>bitsy
gremlin> g = new BitsyGraph(dbPath)
08:04:03.392 [main] INFO  c.l.b.s.FileBackedMemoryGraphStore - Starting graph FileBackedMemoryGraphStore-2(path = /tmp/bitsy)
...
08:04:03.505 [main] DEBUG com.lambdazen.bitsy.store.LoadTask - Using RecordReader for CommittableFileLog(/tmp/bitsy/txB.txt)
==>bitsygraph[/tmp/bitsy]
```

Comment: Hello Stephen,
 thanks for the reply. The above steps worked. I guess :), well i just want to run some basic commands for now on the console. I had created a BitsyDB with 4 vertices and 3 edges and stored them. After i imported this DB i just wanted to check the same from the console, but when i ran commands like

Comment: g.V.count()
it returned a 0. 
Also looks like when i loaded the new DB there was a error with the txB.txt

    03:30:01.393 [main] WARN  com.lambdazen.bitsy.store.LoadTask - Zapped file /home/ubuntu/BitsyDB1/txB.txt to recover from error
    03:30:01.393 [main] INFO  com.lambdazen.bitsy.store.LoadTask -  Recovery of /home/ubuntu/BitsyDB1/txB.txt is complete
    ==>bitsygraph[/home/ubuntu/BitsyDB1]

@stephenmallette

Comment: Is it possible you didn't shut down Bitsy properly when you first created it?  What happens if you create your graph all within the Gremlin Console?  Does everything work properly then?